# Closure not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JS code for ZeroClipBoard :

```
onComplete: function(item) {

            var text= $(item).html();//Not working when I hover the clip
           //var text= 'Hello';// This is working when I hover the clip

            var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
            clip.setHandCursor(true);

            clip.addEventListener('complete', function(client, text) {
                debugstr("Copied text to clipboard: " + text );
            });

            clip.addEventListener('mouseOver', function(client) {
                clip.setText(text);
            })

            // glue specifying our button AND its container
            clip.glue('id_clip_button', 'id_clip_container');

        },
```

Above oncomplete is oneofmy function which is called on some action . I get item from it which is html element.
Now in the above code :

```
        var text= $(item).html();//Not working when I hover the clip
       //var text= 'Hello';// This is working when I hover the clip
```

If I comment the first line and uncomment the second line the clip is working and text is getting copied to clipboard . But I have to use the value of that html element while copying the text . So how should I go with this ? I am getting the value of control at this point

var text= $(item).html();//

But when the hover function is called it is lost. I was thinking that it will be preserved via Closure. Am I missing something ? I am not able to get the value of text at this line :

```
clip.setText(text);
```

Comment: Can you tell us what `console.log(item)` gives? And, `console.log($(item).length)`.

Comment: BOX9 , you are back :) I know what you are asking. I am perfectly getting the jQuery object , it's length is 1 .

Comment: I am :) Can I ask, what is the `onComplete` for on the first line? - is it the ZeroClipBoard event or something else?

Comment: Something else. I have custom JS class and oncomplete is one of its method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer here [Closure not working in ZeroClipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844475/closure-not-working-in-zeroclipboard)